# How do I change the color of a JButton with actionListener

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I have the following JFrame.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/leuoC.png)

It contains a JButton[100] of square and circle JButtons. I want to change their color when I click on them. So I use actionListener for that. But when I write the actionListener to change the color it gives me an exception

**Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 100 out of bounds for length 100**

and it says that the exception is at the b[i].setBackground(Color.blue); inside the actionListener.
I've searched a lot and nothing is changing the color but just gives the exception.
Here is my code

**Subject.java**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Subject extends JFrame{
    public Subject() {
        super("Subject");
        p = new JPanel(new GridLayout(10,10));
        b = new JButton[100];
        Random r = new Random();
        for(i=0;i<100;i++) {
            y = r.nextInt(2) +1;
            if(y==1) {
                b[i] = new JButton();
                b[i].setBackground(Color.black);
                b[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(35,35));
                p.add(b[i]);
            }else {
                b[i] = new Circle();
                b[i].setBackground(Color.black);
                p.add(b[i]);
            }
            b[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    b[i].setBackground(Color.blue);
                }
            }); 
        }
        add(p);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocation(100,200);
    }
    
    private JPanel p;
    private JButton[] b;
    private int i, y;
    
}
```

**Circle.java**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Circle extends JButton{
    public Circle() {
        setBackground(Color.red);
        setFocusable(false);
     
        /*
         These statements enlarge the button so that it 
         becomes a circle rather than an oval.
        */
        Dimension size = getPreferredSize();
        size.width = size.height = Math.min(35,35);
        setPreferredSize(size);
     
        /*
         This call causes the JButton not to paint the background.
         This allows us to paint a round background.
        */
        setContentAreaFilled(false);
      }
     
      protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        if (getModel().isArmed()) {
          g.setColor(Color.yellow);
        } else {
          g.setColor(getBackground());
        }
        g.fillOval(0, 0, getSize().width - 1, getSize().height - 1);
        JLabel l = new JLabel("Click Me");
        
        super.paintComponent(g);
      }
     
      protected void paintBorder(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.darkGray);
        g.drawOval(0, 0, getSize().width - 1, getSize().height - 1);
      }
     
      // Hit detection.
      Shape shape;
     
      public boolean contains(int x, int y) {
        // If the button has changed size,  make a new shape object.
        if (shape == null || !shape.getBounds().equals(getBounds())) {
          shape = new Ellipse2D.Float(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        }
        return shape.contains(x, y);
      }
}
```

I've also tried the following but nothing has changed.

```
b[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (e.getSource()==b[i])
                    {
                        b[i].setBackground(Color.blue);
                    }
                }
            });
```

Does anyone have any advice on what to do to fix it? Thank you!

Comment: For why you ware facing `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 100` it is because at `b[i].setBackground(Color.blue);` you are using `i` which is *class field* which after loop will end will hold value `100` making each listener want to execute `b[100].setBackground(..)`. Now question is: why did you make it a field? Is it because when you declared `i` in `for (int i = 0;  ...)` compiler complained that anonymous classes can access only final or effectively final *local variables*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply change the following line in your `actionPerformed()` method...

```java
b[i].setBackground(Color.blue);
```

to this...

```java
((JButton) e.getSource()).setBackground(Color.blue);
```

You are creating a separate, anonymous class (that implements `ActionListener` interface) for each `JButton`. Hence the `ActionEvent` source can **only** be the `JButton` that you created the anonymous class for.

Note that after you compile your java code, you will have a separate class file for each `ActionListener`. The class file names will begin with `Subject$` and end with `.class`, for example:

```
Subject$1.class
Subject$2.class
Subject$3.class
```

There will be at least 100 of these classes since you have created one for each `JButton`.

Comment: Can you also include reasoning behind that change so OP (and other readers) would know what mistake to avoid?

Comment: @Abra thank you. I would never thought of doing that

Comment: @knowsnothing, *There will be at least 100 of these classes* - So the better implementation is to NOT create a unique ActionListener for every 
 button. Instead the ActionListener should be created outside the loop and then you just share the same ActionListener for each button. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23468884/java-event-keypress-keyboard/23475796#23475796 for a working example of this approach.